# How to create a list of values from a dictionary array?

Tags: python, boto3

I'm writing a Python script using Boto. When I do a describe I get a list of dicts with 10 items. Here is sample output:

```
[{
    "arn": "arn:aws:health:us-east-1::event/EC2/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED5ac93e9d-18fb-49a0-bd93-9b23c81f23bd",
    "service": "EC2",
    "eventTypeCode": "AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED",
    "eventTypeCategory": "scheduledChange",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "startTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "endTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "lastUpdatedTime": "2019-05-17 13:29:54.458000-04:00",
    "statusCode": "upcoming"
}, {
    "arn": "arn:aws:health:us-east-1::event/EC2/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED67080365-2d7d-4f63-8d74-ab67995b7f55",
    "service": "EC2",
    "eventTypeCode": "AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED",
    "eventTypeCategory": "scheduledChange",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "startTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "endTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "lastUpdatedTime": "2019-05-17 13:29:50.932000-04:00",
    "statusCode": "upcoming"
}, {
    "arn": "arn:aws:health:us-east-1::event/EC2/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED30e49b6a-0729-42aa-bcea-7a5f1d15368e",
    "service": "EC2",
    "eventTypeCode": "AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED",
    "eventTypeCategory": "scheduledChange",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "startTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "endTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "lastUpdatedTime": "2019-05-17 13:29:47.118000-04:00",
    "statusCode": "upcoming"
}, {
    "arn": "arn:aws:health:us-east-1::event/EC2/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED8226db8a-7d54-4495-882f-9f4e2a09757b",
    "service": "EC2",
    "eventTypeCode": "AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED",
    "eventTypeCategory": "scheduledChange",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "startTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "endTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "lastUpdatedTime": "2019-05-17 13:29:43.011000-04:00",
    "statusCode": "upcoming"
}, {
    "arn": "arn:aws:health:us-east-1::event/EC2/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED269202de-d110-4cc2-8a58-b60d830ff188",
    "service": "EC2",
    "eventTypeCode": "AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED",
    "eventTypeCategory": "scheduledChange",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "startTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "endTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "lastUpdatedTime": "2019-05-17 13:29:38.433000-04:00",
    "statusCode": "upcoming"
}, {
    "arn": "arn:aws:health:us-east-1::event/EC2/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED4d6677ff-8250-4d3a-bb06-ebf5efd59079",
    "service": "EC2",
    "eventTypeCode": "AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED",
    "eventTypeCategory": "scheduledChange",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "startTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "endTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "lastUpdatedTime": "2019-05-17 13:29:34.988000-04:00",
    "statusCode": "upcoming"
}, {
    "arn": "arn:aws:health:us-east-1::event/EC2/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED973f686a-f03f-4a28-a966-129e3f36d0f0",
    "service": "EC2",
    "eventTypeCode": "AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED",
    "eventTypeCategory": "scheduledChange",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "startTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "endTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "lastUpdatedTime": "2019-05-17 13:29:32.072000-04:00",
    "statusCode": "upcoming"
}, {
    "arn": "arn:aws:health:us-east-1::event/EC2/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED067b4edf-e984-4595-8d96-89e5cdcb82ee",
    "service": "EC2",
    "eventTypeCode": "AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED",
    "eventTypeCategory": "scheduledChange",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "startTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "endTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "lastUpdatedTime": "2019-05-17 13:29:29.616000-04:00",
    "statusCode": "upcoming"
}, {
    "arn": "arn:aws:health:us-east-1::event/EC2/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED21b61601-6342-4e23-b3c3-d4384eccdd61",
    "service": "EC2",
    "eventTypeCode": "AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED",
    "eventTypeCategory": "scheduledChange",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "startTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "endTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "lastUpdatedTime": "2019-05-17 13:29:24.326000-04:00",
    "statusCode": "upcoming"
}, {
    "arn": "arn:aws:health:us-east-1::event/EC2/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED/AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED13bf770d-9a7a-4434-be3d-9d4f1d162d66",
    "service": "EC2",
    "eventTypeCode": "AWS_EC2_PERSISTENT_INSTANCE_RETIREMENT_SCHEDULED",
    "eventTypeCategory": "scheduledChange",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "startTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "endTime": "2019-05-31 13:00:00-04:00",
    "lastUpdatedTime": "2019-05-17 13:29:21.642000-04:00",
    "statusCode": "upcoming"
}]
```

Now I want to create a list with just the ARN of each item. I can loop through each item like:

```
for i in len(var1):
  var2.append(var1[i]['arn']
print var2
```

but is there a better way that writing this loop ?

Comment: Define "better".  If the code you have gives you the result you want, why stop to question it?  Just move on I say.

Comment: @Steve please don't format JSON as a quote. It's code, and formatting it as a quote makes it unreadable.

Comment: @Zoe - oops, got it - definitely looks nice now :) - was thinking it was "data", not "code", but of course it's both.  It's even both JSON (Javascript) and Python, in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list comprehension will do it most compactly:

```
arns = [x['arn'] for x in data]
```

Comment: I would say you need a try/except block in there in case `x['arn'` returns an error (the dict `x` doesn't have key `'arn'`)

Comment: @EricJin and @HarshikaMahesh see my answer below that uses `.get()` to handle a missing `'arn'`

Comment: Probably more useful as the `.get()` method can be squeezed in one line, while `try: arns = [x['arn'] for x in data]; except Exception: pass` takes two.

Comment: Just popped back in here.  I do a lot of this sort of thing with AWS and Boto.  In cases like this, you're usually safe making assumptions about the data you get back from AWS.  Sure, technically, putting in some unexpected data catching code is more correct.  This was just a basic answer to the OPs question of if there was an alternative way to go about the basic issue.

Answer (score 0):

The more idiomatic way to do the same would be to iterate over the list directly, rather than tracking an index:

```py
for thing in var1:
    var2.append(thing['arn'])
```

Assuming `var2` is a `list`, otherwise if it's working, you're probably fine

Answer (score 0):

Adding a third answer with some better error handling. You can use the `.get()` dictionary method to safely get the value from your dictionary. This allows you to control behavior if `'arn'` is not in the dictionary for some reason, instead of your code failing.

`arns = [x.get('arn', 'missing arn') for x in data]`

if by better you mean fastest, then the strict list comprehension is the best, roughly 2x a for loop 2.25x faster than list comprehension with get. If speed is your highest priority, and you know you'll always have `arn` in your dict, go with the list comprehension. If you're concerned about not having `arn` ever, go with the `.get()` method.

```
def list_comp(data):
    return [x['arn'] for x in data]

def for_loop(data):
    var2 = []
    for thing in data:
        var2.append(thing['arn'])
    return var2

def list_comp_get(data):
    return [x.get('arn', 'missing arn') for x in data]

%timeit list_comp(arns)
561 ns ± 4.78 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit for_loop(arns)
910 ns ± 2.59 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit list_comp_get(arns)
1.22 µs ± 1.32 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

list_comp(arns) == for_loop(arns) == list_comp_get(arns)
True
```